# Is this method of solving a 401 with IIS safe?

Tags: iis

I had problems with getting a 401 when visiting my website.
I found a lot of "solutions" online that sadly didn't work for me.

The one that did work was this:

> In IIS, select the website you're having the issue with. In the IIS
> section, select 'Authentication'. Right click on Anonymous
> Authentication and select 'Edit' Check the 'Specified User' radio
> button and click on 'Set' I entered my username, password and password
> confirmation and click ok.

Here some screenshots, cause it might help other people.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering however, since I don't see this solution being mentioned somewhere else, is this approach safe?

Comment: Web apps are so easy to be hacked, so setting an administrator as anonymous user is unwise. Hire a security professional and you can learn more about how things are supposed to work together. A place for specific questions like this won't teach you all you need. BTW, using this way to resolve 401 (likely 401.3) is completely wrong, and you should instead properly plan and configure NTFS permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, from a security perspective, it is not recommended to set up an administrator user as an anonymous account for anonymous authentication.

If you specify a user account with elevated privileges (such as an administrator account), you may expose sensitive system resources to unauthorized access. This can be a significant security risk.

Additionally, storing usernames and passwords in the IIS configuration can be risky. If someone gains access to your server's configuration or there's a breach, these credentials could be compromised.

If you are setting up anonymous authentication credentials, you should follow the principle of least privilege. Please grant the new account only the minimum permissions on the IIS server computer. Granting too many permissions(such as administrative access) to anonymous users can compromise security.

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication#how-to-change-anonymous-authentication-credentials-from-the-iusr-account